# Copy List of class variable without reference dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to copy myList to _newList. I tried List.from(), [...mylist] and other method but It does not work.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>>? mylist;
  MyWidget({required this.mylist, Key? key}) : super(key: key);
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _newList = [];
  _copyList() {
    _newList = List.castFrom(widget.mylist!);
  }
}
```

Comment: The approaches you describe will create new `List` objects, but the elements will refer to the same `Map` objects.  There is no way to make a *deep* copy of a `List`; you must do it manually: `_newList = [for (var map in widget.mylist ?? []) {...map}];`.  Note that that will not be a deep copy either since the copied `Map`s will refer to the same keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work...

```dart
List<Map<String, dynamic>> copyMyList(List<Map<String, dynamic>> oldList) {
  final newList = [...myList];
  return newList;
}
```

Also, I'd suggest to move out logic from widget building.

Finally, this is so simple you shouldn't need a function to do that.

`final newList = [...oldList];` should be more than enough.

Your code probably doesn't work because you're writing that `_copyList` closure inside the `build` methods with no type annotations, nor invocations.

Make sure your review [Dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour) and coding in general before venturing into Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Use spread operator.

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> get copiedList => [...myList];
```

or you can make it function to reuse everywhere

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> copyList (List<Map<String, dynamic>> list) => [...list];
```